# Build, compress, optimize tool for ros+linux to OS dedicated

Tags: ros, optimization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

It will be possible to have?
or is someone work in?

a tool to build a small app+OS dedicated, based on our stack. I mean, that compress and optimize:

- the sources files of our app build on top of ros
- linux kernel, ros-core and  dependencies.

Which will result in a tar with:

1. optimized+clean SO linux
2. optimized+clean ROS
3. our stack/node!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33033/build,-compress,-optimize-tool-for-ros+linux-to-os-dedicated/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of anyone with a toolchain dedicated to building "optimized" OS images.  The standard technique used at the moment is to install Ubuntu and the Ubuntu packages for the stack/nodes required.  For example see the [TurtleBot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Robot%20Setup)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1